# Rails: set statement timeout only for frontend (not for Sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timeout, sidekiq

I see that there is a way to set a timeout:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688245/51387

**Is there any way to add the statement timeout only to the frontend and not to Sidekiq?** i.e. in the background workers it is acceptable to have long running queries

Comment: This can be possible if you are running Sidekiq instance in a separate container. Set timeout value in an env variable, and use that env variable in database.yml. Set different value in env variable for Sidekiq container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a deploy time issue. Whatever process starts your web servers should set an appropriate environment variable. `export WEB_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT=2`

Or reverse it: have the default very short, and set an override environment variable for your workers, allowing a much longer sql execution time.

```
   defaults: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    pool: 5
    min_messages: warning
    variables:
      statement_timeout: <%= ENV["WEB_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT"].present? ? ENV["WEB_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT"] : 600 %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ActiveJob, how about simply running the solution proposed in the question you've linked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763517/8271939) in a `before_perform` block?

Something like this:

```rb
before_perform { ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET statement_timeout = '10s'") }
```

This way, you can leave your overall `database.yml` untouched and only inject the extended timeout in your background jobs.